# How to add graph end points in graphQL

Tags: java, spring, graphql

I was using graphQl starter to have a graph endpoint, but we had to add extra versions to the endpoints, so I switched to graphql-java and I need to add an extra graph endpoint, on the research I found that I should make a graphQlSchema with all it goes. I'm having a "nested exception is graphql.AssertException: you must provide a data fetcher". Cant move on from this

````js
@Component
    public class NewGraphQLSchema {
    @Resource
    GetAllBrandsDataFetcher getAllBrandsDataFetcher;
    String schemaPath = "src/main/resources/graphql/schema.graphqls";
    String schema;
    SchemaParser schemaParser = new SchemaParser();
    TypeDefinitionRegistry typeDefinitionRegistry;
    RuntimeWiring runtimeWiring = buildRuntimeWiring();
    SchemaGenerator schemaGenerator = new SchemaGenerator();
    GraphQLSchema graphQLSchema;
    @Getter
    GraphQL graphQL;

    {
        try {
            schema = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(schemaPath)));
            typeDefinitionRegistry = schemaParser.parse(schema);
            graphQLSchema = schemaGenerator.makeExecutableSchema(typeDefinitionRegistry, runtimeWiring);
            graphQL = GraphQL.newGraphQL(graphQLSchema).build();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("No se pudo cargar el esquema", e);
        }
    }

    private RuntimeWiring buildRuntimeWiring() {
        return RuntimeWiring.newRuntimeWiring()
                .type(TypeRuntimeWiring.newTypeWiring("Query")
                        .dataFetcher("getAllBrands", getAllBrandsDataFetcher))
                .build();
    }

}
```

And the GetAllBrandsDataFetcher 


```@Component
public class GetAllBrandsDataFetcher implements DataFetcher<List<BrandsDto>> {
    @Resource
    private BrandsService brandsService;

    @Override
    public List<BrandsDto> get(DataFetchingEnvironment environment) {
        try {
            return brandsService.getAllBrands();
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error al obtener todas las marcas", e);
        }
    }
}
````

Java 8, graphql-java 20.1

I dont know what to try now, I'm kinda new to not starter graphql